# java image upload using html5 error "Invalid argument to native writeImage"

Tags: java

I am trying to use html 5 image upload, but the problem I'm facing is when I try to decode the 64 encoded image it throws some error, here is my code:

```
public String decodeToImage() throws IOException {

    destPath = "/home/user/deskTop";

    byte[] imageByte;

    String imageData = request.getParameter("img");

    String base64Image = imageData.split(",")[1];

    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

    imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64Image);

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte));

    File outputfile = new File(destPath, "11111.png");

    try 
    {
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

When I am trying to write the image in File from Buffer Image it throws this error:

```
"Invalid argument to native writeImage"
```

When I asked the error elsewhere, someone said that it may be because of using open-jdk.

Here is my JavaScriot:

```
crop = function() {
        //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
        var crop_canvas,
            left = $('.imgOverlay').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
            top = $('.imgOverlay').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
            width = $('.imgOverlay').width(),
            height = $('.imgOverlay').height();

        crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        crop_canvas.width = width;
        crop_canvas.height = height;

        crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
        var onSuccesOfUpload = function(data) {
            alert();
        };
        var onErrorOfUpload = function(data) {
            alert();
        };
        var data = function(data) {
            alert();
        };
        var data = {
            'img': crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
        };
        callToDB('/canvasImageUpload.action', 'POST', data, onSuccesOfUpload, onErrorOfUpload);

    }
```